# How set auto day/night mode google maps in Xamarin Forms

Tags: google-maps, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I need to set the night mode Google maps, which will work automatically using the sensor in the phone and manual using the switch. I need some example or documentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install the `Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps` Nuget Package (source code available on [GitHub](https://github.com/amay077/Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps))
which has already implemented it on Xamarin.Forms.

You can refer to the MapStylePage sample available [here](https://github.com/amay077/Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps/blob/master/XFGoogleMapSample/XFGoogleMapSample/MapStylePage.xaml.cs) which basically explains you how to create original map styles using [MapStyle With Google](https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/). You can use the wizard, select the Night theme from there and get the corresponding json style, which you'll use on your Xamarin app.

Answer (score -1):

```
int currentNightMode = getResources().getConfiguration().uiMode
        & Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_MAS

switch (currentNightMode) {
    case Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_NO:
        // Night mode is not active, we're in day time
    case Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_YES:
        // Night mode is active, we're at night!
    case Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_UNDEFINED:
        // We don't know what mode we're in, assume notnight
}
```