# How can I apply a style or change colors in map using Xamarin.Forms.Maps (No Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps)

Tags: xamarin.forms, custom-renderer, xamarin.forms.maps

As I wrote in the title, I use the Microsoft Xamarin.Forms.Maps nugget to show map in my app.
First I started with Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps, but when I saw that I can't customise InfoWindows (when I touch one pin), I must go back and start using Xamarin.Forms.Maps.
The only problem is that I have to apply a "gray style" to the map or something similar. And I can't find any link or guide to do this.
It seems that CustomRender can't modify style or colors.

Please, can someone help me? Any links, documentation or examples?

Comment: What do you mean by "gray style"?

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to `Dark Mode` you can create custom renderer to achieve that .

#### iOS

Set `OverrideUserInterfaceStyle`  in `OnElementChanged` .

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Map), typeof(MyRenderer))]
namespace FormsApp.iOS
{
    class MyRenderer : MapRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<View> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            if (e.NewElement != null)
            {
                var nativeMap = Control as MKMapView;
                nativeMap.OverrideUserInterfaceStyle = UIUserInterfaceStyle.Dark;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### Android

Create a dark mode file in resource and set `mapStyle` in `OnElementChanged` .

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Map), typeof(MyMapRenderer))]
namespace FormsApp.Droid
{
    class MyMapRenderer : MapRenderer
    {
        Context _context;

        public MyMapRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
            _context = context;        
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Map> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if(e.NewElement != null)
            {
                NativeMap.SetMapStyle(MapStyleOptions.LoadRawResourceStyle(this.Context, Resource.Raw.map_style_night));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Refer to

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/429548/#Comment_429548.

[How to use Dark Mode Google Maps in Xamarin.Forms.Maps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67864937/how-to-use-dark-mode-google-maps-in-xamarin-forms-maps).

Comment: I refer for example something like this: https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/.

Comment: For example, if I create in this website (mapstyle.withgoogle.com) my style map, am I able to set the mapstyle whit the custom render that you show?

Comment: I think that your refer links talking about a Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMap, and I use Xamarin.Forms.Maps. Is  there any solution to make a personal style using this nugget?

Comment: No , this is the solution for Xamarin.Forms.Maps , click into that link for details.